# Showing Piecewise Function is not Onto

Tags: functions

I need to prove that $f(x)=\begin{cases}2-x & x\le1\\ \frac{1}{x}& x\gt1 \\ \end{cases}$ is not onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Proof.

I believe I need to find a $y \in Y$ such that $\forall x \in X$, $f(x)\not=y$.

$f(x)\not=-2$. No $x \le 1$ cannot yield $y=-2$ because $2-x$ will always be $\ge 1$

Does this suffice? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: This suffices and is a perfectly reasonable example.  All you need is one example for it to be shown not to be onto.

Comment: I would have chosen $0$ myself, but your $-2$ works just as well

Comment: Your argument that $-2$ is missed also needs to point out that $\frac 1x \ne -2$ for any $x > 1$. (It is obvious, but barely more so than the case you did show.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check that
$$f(\mathbb{R})=[1,+\infty[\cup ]0,1[=]0,+\infty[.$$

Comment: This answer does not answer the question of "*does this (example above) suffice?*"  While, yes what you say is true and correct... it is not generally in a student's best interest to exactly find the range in its entirety rather than finding a single quick and readily available example which is more than good enough.

Comment: In general i would agree but here the range is trivial to find. Also, it allows to find his point in an explicit mathematical way : any negative number does the job